# string manipulation to extract substring of particular pattern

Tags: c#

I have the following string in c#

```
Count([AssignedTo]) as [AssignedTo] , Sum([Billing Amount]) as [Billing Amount] , Max([Billing Rate]) as [Billing Rate] , Min([ExecutionDate]) as [ExecutionDate] , Average([HoursSpent]) as [HoursSpent] , [Project], [Sub-Project], [TaskName], [Vendor], [Work Classification], [Work Done], Count([WorkItemType]) as [WorkItemType]
```

Now I want list of all fields having aggregate function , through string manipulation or `linq`

**output like**

```
Count([AssignedTo])

 Sum([Billing Amount])

 Max([Billing Rate])

 Min([ExecutionDate])

 Average([HoursSpent]) 

Count([WorkItemType])
```

Comment: @Dwonvoters please have mercy to comment atleast

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it was probably because you haven't demonstrated that you have tried anything to solve this for yourself.  Folks here are happy to help with specific questions, but we aren't here to write all your code for you.  Clues : You have a STRING that you will need to SPLIT into parts, and then see if each part STARTSWITH a specific string from a LIST of possibles.

Comment: yes @ZombieSheep i tried to google it but nothing worth to post , so i wrote , not finding any idea

Comment: A more descriptive question perhaps with some code, and details like whether you are trying to print to console or trying to process etc., would help you get the answer quickly. For example the string you specified in the first line is not a valid C# string literal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this works for you:

```
var aggr = new []{ "Count", "Sum", "Max", "Min", "Average"};
var allAggregates = text.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(col => new{ col, token = col.TrimStart().Split().First() })
    .Where(x => x.token.Contains('(') && aggr.Any(a => x.token.StartsWith(a, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
    .Select(x => x.token);
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/U2JpTt)</kbd>

> can i get the field name only which is inside function

I prefer string methods instead of regex if possible:

```
var allAggregates = text.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(col => new { col, token = col.TrimStart().Split().First() })
    .Where(x => x.token.Contains('(') && aggr.Any(a => x.token.StartsWith(a, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
    .Select(x => {
        string innerPart = x.token.Substring(x.token.IndexOf('(') + 1);
        int index = innerPart.IndexOf(')');
        if (index >= 0)
            innerPart = innerPart.Remove(index);
        return innerPart;
    });
```

Comment: you always rock, Thanks dude, perfect solution

Comment: can  i get the field name only which is inside function

Answer (score 0):

```
var aggregates = new []{ "Count", "Sum", "Max", "Min", "Average"};
var output=Regex.Matches(input,@"(\w+)\(.*?\)")
                .Cast<Match>()
                .Where(x=>aggregates.Any(y=>y==x.Groups[1].Value))
                .Select(z=>z.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another way:

```
string[] funcNames =  new string[]{"Sum","Average","Count","Max","Min"};
string s = "Your String";

var output = from v in s.Split(',')  
             where funcNames.Contains(v.Split('(')[0].Trim())
             select v.Split(new string[]{" as "},  
                            StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0].Trim();
             .Split('(')[1].Split(')')[0]; //this line is to get only field names

//Print results
foreach(var str in output) Console.WriteLine(str);
```